# How to compare date variable with a given time?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array with time values like 2020-02-17 10:00:00 AM.

I'm trying to write an if statement that executes when the time value is between two values.

```
If starttime(i) >= #10:00:00 AM# Then
    If starttime(i) < #10:30:00 AM# Then
```

The first value in the array is 2020-02-17 10:00:00 AM and it passes the first line but not the second.

It passes the first line even if I write

```
If starttime(i) >= #10:10:00 AM# Then
```

Why might this be?

Comment: `If starttime(i) >= CVDate("10:10:00 AM") Then`

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then what is the value of `starttime(i)`? Are you sure it's a date? Or is it a string that looks like a date? Maybe include its definition and how it is populated in your question. That would be helpful to know.

Comment: Also, you may want to include the actual date in the value you are comparing, instead of just the time, as that matters too. `If starttime(i) >= CVDate("2020-02-17 10:10:00 AM") Then` or convert `starttime(i)` to a `time only` value to compare it.

Comment: You're comparing a `Date` literal without the date portion, with a `Date` value; if you mean to compare times and ignore the date portion, use the [TimeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function) function to strip the date part: `If TimeValue(starttime(i)) >= TimeValue(#10:00:00 AM#) Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#10:00:00 AM#` might look and read like a **time** literal value, it's not. VBA does not have any `Time` data type, this is a `Date` literal value, with an implicit *date* portion and a *time* part that says it's 10 AM.

Use the [`TimeValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function) function to strip the `Date` part and only work with times.

> ```
> If starttime(i) >= #10:10:00 AM# Then
> ```

That condition is always `True`, because the implicit `Date` part of the `#10:10:00 AM#` date literal is `CDate(0)`, which is always going to be smaller than any other valid date value.

```
Debug.Print Year(#10:00:00 AM#), Month(#10:00:00 AM#), Day(#10:00:00 AM#)
 1899          12            30
```

1899-12-30 is what `0` evaluates to as a date.

```
If TimeValue(starttime(i)) >= TimeValue(#10:00:00 AM#) Then
    If TimeValue(starttime(i)) < TimeValue(#10:30:00 AM#) Then
```